# How to Unit Test the SortingDataAccessor of DataSource MatTableDataSource

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

Am not able to Cover the following lines of code?

```
 this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
                    switch (property) {
                        case 'status': return item.status;
                        case 'description': return item.description;
                        default: return item[property];
                    }
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've ever found a solution, but I also needed the test coverage for something similar to yours. You'll have to make multiple tests to cover each switch case, but it's generally the same structure below for each. I'm hoping this helps you or others who are also struggling on this.

Example 1 (component.ts)

```
    this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item: any, property: any) => {
  switch (property) {
    case 'card.age': return item.value.card.age;
    default: return item.value[property];
  }
};
```

Example 1 (component.spec.ts)

```
    it('should sort by "card.age" when property is "card.age"', () => {
  const mockData = { value: { card: { name: 'card 1', age: '2' } } };
  const result = component.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor(mockData, 'card.age');

  expect(result).toBe('2');
});
```

Example 2 (component.ts)

```
    this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor =
  (data: AbstractControl, sortHeaderId: string) => {
  const value: any = data.value[sortHeaderId];
  return typeof value === "string" ? value.toLowerCase() : value;
};
```

Example 2 (component.spec.ts)

```
    it('should use sorting data accessor', () => {
  const mockData = { value: { name: 'example name' } };
  const sortingDataAccessor = component.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor;
  const result = sortingDataAccessor(mockData, 'name');

  expect(result).toBe('example name');
});
```

In example 1, in my case I had a bunch of FormGroups in a FormArray so I had to get the 'value' of the item first to access the actual item and its properties.